# ViewPager - update view after adapter got empty

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` with a `ViewPager`.

Everything is working fine. If I open my activity with an empty Adapter, the `ViewPager`is empty, if I add items, the `ViewPager` updates correctly.

BUT, if I open my activity and delete the last item of my `ViewPager`, the `ViewPager`does not invalidate correctly and keeps the last `Fragment` visible.

How can I avoid this?

I'm using my library, it's a wrapper class for ViewPager + ViewPagerIndicator + FragmentPager(State)Adapter:

- The class itself is placed here: https://github.com/MichaelFlisar/PagerManager/blob/master/src/com/michaelflisar/pagermanager/MFragmentPagerStateAdapter.java
- The implementation is placed here: https://github.com/MichaelFlisar/PagerManager/blob/master/src/com/michaelflisar/pagermanager/MPagerAdapterHelper.java

It implements a simple FragmentStatePagerAdapter with weak references to it's fragments...

My code looks like following:

```
mPagerManager = new MPagerManager<ExerciseViewFragment, MFragmentPagerStateAdapter<ExerciseViewFragment>>(pager, tpi,
            new MFragmentPagerStateAdapter<ExerciseViewFragment>(fragmentManager)
            {
                @Override
                public CharSequence getPageTitle(int pos)
                {
                    return mData.workout.getWExercise().get(pos).getExercise().getName();
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount()
                {
                    return mData.workout.getWExercise().size();
                }

                @Override
                public ExerciseViewFragment createFragment(int pos)
                {
                    return ExerciseViewFragment.newInstance(pos, mData.workout.getWExercise());
                }
            });
```

**I'm calling `mPagerManager.notifyDataSetChanged();` which forwards the call to the FragmentPagerStateAdapter directly...**

PS: I know, I can make it invisible, if item count is 0... But I'm wondering if there's a better solution

Comment: can you upload some piece of code ? cause if hard to tell you something with this information only.

Comment: added the links to my library and some more infos...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I thought you might still need to know what to do. It's very common issue. ViewPager does not invalid views which are already created(including these which are ready on the left and right side of your current view).
Solving this is very easy. Just implement the following method in your adapter like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

By default this method returns PagerAdapter.POSITION_UNCHANGED.

For most developers this method usage is misleading, I had this problem myself till I realised that this method is used by `ViewPager.dataSetChanged()` to establish which items should be recreated. With above code you tell ViewPager to recreate all items whenever data set change.